# If $\mathbf{Grp}$ is not an Abelian category, how can one define cohomology?

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am reading through Rotman's homological algebra at the moment and I noticed that there is a great deal of effort spent on setting up the notion of an Abelian category as "the most general object one can do homology/cohomology in".

Yet I am suprised to see that Group cohomology exists. Don't get me wrong, I understand the validity of constructing cohomology for groups but I just don't see how it relates to the usual cohomology with Abelian categories.

I'm expecting to see something like: I put this category to do with some group (maybe ${}_{\Bbb ZG}\mathbf{Mod}$?) into the cohomology functor $H_{\mathcal A}(B,A)$ and I should magically get out group cohomology. But it isn't this simple is it?

So really what I am asking is: Is group cohomology and Abelian category cohomology really the same thing?

Comment: You take "Abelian category cohomology" in the category of $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules, as you suggested

Comment: Group cohomology does not take place in the category of groups. In fact, there is most of the time only a single group under consideration at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by "abelian category cohomology"?  What does the notation $H_\mathcal{A}(B,A)$ mean?